# Perform for loop inside where clause, POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```sql
  WITH 
reference AS (SELECT row_number() over() as id, ue_tac, ue_model, ue_vendor, min(ue_ref_rac)AS MIN1
  FROM "LTE_FLOW"
  WHERE not ue_tac IS NULL
  Group by ue_tac, ue_model, ue_vendor ),

    
    data1 as (
        SELECT bL.id, bL.ue_ref_rac, bL.mmes1apid,
        ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_path_query(bL.combList, '$[*].bandList."eutra"')) as eutras, -- 3 records
        ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_path_query(bL.combList, '$[*].bandList."nr"')) as nrs, -- 2 records
        ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_path_query(bL.combListV1540, '$."bandList-v1540"[*]."srs-TxSwitch"."supportedSRS-TxPortSwitch"')) as SupportedSRSTxPortSwitch -- 5
   
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
            row_number() over() as id,
            a.combList,
            a.combListV1540,
            jsonb_path_query(a.combList::jsonb, '$.featureSetCombination') as featureSetCombinationIndex,
            a.ue_ref_rac, a.mmes1apid,
            a.layer3
            from 
            (
                SELECT
                    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"[*]') as combList,
                    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList-v1540"[*]') as combListV1540,
                    layer3,
                   ue_ref_rac, mmes1apid
                FROM "S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION" --LIMIT 2000
```

I need to make a where clause in-order not to search in Millions of records, so I use this where:

```sql
                where ue_ref_rac = (select reference.MIN1 FROM reference)
```

But I got this message:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

[image]

Here is the rest of my query:

```sql
            ) as a
        ) bL
    ),
    data2 AS(
        SELECT id,
            array_agg(downlinkSetNR) AS downlinkSetNR,
            array_agg(downIndexCC) AS downIndexCC,
            array_agg(Downfr1) as Downfr1,
            array_agg("maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH") AS "maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
            array_agg(supportedModulationOrderDL) as supportedModulationOrderDL,
            array_agg(supportedSubcarrierSpacingDL) as supportedSubcarrierSpacingDL
        FROM
        (
            SELECT id,
                downlinkSetNR,
                downIndexCC,
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsDownlinkPerCC, '$."supportedBandwidthDL"."fr1"') as Downfr1,
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsDownlinkPerCC, '$."supportedModulationOrderDL"') as supportedModulationOrderDL,
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsDownlinkPerCC, '$."maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH"') AS "maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsDownlinkPerCC, '$."supportedSubcarrierSpacingDL"') as supportedSubcarrierSpacingDL
            FROM (
                SELECT id, downlinkSetNR, downIndexCC,
                    jsonb_path_query(c.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-NR-Capability"."featureSets"."featureSetsDownlinkPerCC"[$index-1]', jsonb_build_object('index', downIndexCC)) AS featureSetsDownlinkPerCC
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    b.id, downlinkSetNR,
                    jsonb_path_query(b.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-NR-Capability"."featureSets"."featureSetsDownlink"[$dlsetnr-1]."featureSetListPerDownlinkCC"[0]', jsonb_build_object('dlsetnr', b.downlinkSetNR)) AS downIndexCC,
                    b.layer3
                    FROM (
                        SELECT bL.id,
                        jsonb_path_query(bL.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."featureSetCombinations"[$index][*][*]."nr"."downlinkSetNR"', jsonb_build_object('index', bL.featureSetCombinationIndex)) as downlinkSetNR,
                        bL.layer3
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT 
                            row_number() over() as id,
                            jsonb_path_query(a.combList::jsonb, '$.featureSetCombination') as featureSetCombinationIndex,
                            a.layer3
                            from 
                            (
                                SELECT jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"[*]') as combList,
                                layer3
                                FROM "S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION" --LIMIT 2000
                                where ue_ref_rac = reference.MIN1 FROM reference
     
                                
                            ) AS a 
                        ) bL
                    ) AS b 
                    WHERE b.downlinkSetNR is not NULL  
                ) as c
            ) as d
        ) AS e
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY id
    ),
    data3 AS(
        SELECT id,
            array_agg(uplinkSetNR) AS uplinkSetNR,
            array_agg(upIndexCC) AS upIndexCC,
            array_agg(UPfr1) as UPfr1,
            --array_agg("maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH") AS "maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
            array_agg(supportedModulationOrderUL) as supportedModulationOrderUL,
            array_agg(supportedSubcarrierSpacingUL) as supportedSubcarrierSpacingUL
        FROM
        (
            SELECT id,
                uplinkSetNR,
                upIndexCC,
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsUplinkPerCC, '$."supportedBandwidthUL"."fr1"') as UPfr1,
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsUplinkPerCC, '$."supportedModulationOrderUL"') as supportedModulationOrderUL,
                --jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsDownlinkPerCC, '$."maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH"') AS "maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
                jsonb_path_query(d.featureSetsUplinkPerCC, '$."supportedSubcarrierSpacingUL"') as supportedSubcarrierSpacingUL
            FROM (
                SELECT id, uplinkSetNR, upIndexCC,
                    jsonb_path_query(c.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-NR-Capability"."featureSets"."featureSetsUplinkPerCC"[$index-1]', jsonb_build_object('index', upIndexCC)) AS featureSetsUplinkPerCC
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    b.id, uplinkSetNR,
                    jsonb_path_query(b.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-NR-Capability"."featureSets"."featureSetsUplink"[$dlsetnr-1]."featureSetListPerUplinkCC"[0]', jsonb_build_object('dlsetnr', b.uplinkSetNR)) AS upIndexCC,
                    b.layer3
                    FROM (
                        SELECT bL.id, 
                        jsonb_path_query(bL.layer3, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."featureSetCombinations"[$index][*][*]."nr"."uplinkSetNR"', jsonb_build_object('index', bL.featureSetCombinationIndex)) as uplinkSetNR,
                        bL.layer3
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT 
                            row_number() over() as id, 
                            jsonb_path_query(a.combList::jsonb, '$.featureSetCombination') as featureSetCombinationIndex,
                            a.layer3
                            from 
                            (
                                SELECT jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"[*]') as combList,
                                layer3
                                FROM "S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION" --LIMIT 2000
                                where ue_ref_rac = (select reference.MIN1 FROM reference)
     
                                
                            ) AS a 
                        ) bL
                    ) AS b 
                    WHERE b.uplinkSetNR is not NULL  
                ) as c
            ) as d
        ) AS e
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY id
    ),
    final_table AS (
    select data1.id,data1.ue_ref_rac, data1.mmes1apid,
        data1.eutras,
        data1.nrs,
        data1.SupportedSRSTxPortSwitch,
        data2.Downfr1,
        data2."maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
        data2.supportedModulationOrderDL,
        data2.supportedSubcarrierSpacingDL,
       data3.Upfr1,
        --data3."maxNumberMIMO-LayersPDSCH",
        data3.supportedModulationOrderUL,
        data3.supportedSubcarrierSpacingUL  
        
    FROM data1 
    LEFT JOIN data2 ON (data1.id = data2.id)
    LEFT JOIN data3 ON (data1.id = data3.id)
    )
    SELECT * FROM final_table
```

The problem I am facing with this code is:
as you can see there is mapping in every query of the code, to make this mapping correct we use the ids in every query (data1, data2, data3), and make these ids as a reference (as you can see in the final table (last 4 lines of code) to left join the three queries (or the three tables).

When we use

```sql
where ue_ref_rac = --specific No
```

we got correct data, but when we remove this where clause, the ids mis match eatch other and we get incorrect data.
So, how can I make this where clause coorect, or how to use For loop inside where clause?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should try to come up with a smaller query that exhibits the problem.

Comment: SQL is a declarative, not imperative, language; therefore, there isn't a `for loop`. Don't approach the problem procedurally, but rather think in terms of operations on sets. The exception occurs because `reference` returns a row for every distinct combination of a non-NULL `ue_tac`, `ue_model`, and `ue_vendor`. Please post queries as a single block instead of splitting them. It's also helpful to provide table DDL so others can easily evaluate alternative queries. It's difficult to provide effective assistance without sufficient context (e.g., sample input and expected output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a given `S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION.ue_ref_rac` is on your list of MIN1's, you'll need [`IN ()` or `=ANY()` comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) that matches your mental model of a "for loop" iterating over the many rows returned from your subquery expression and checking if ***any*** of those matches your `ue_ref_rac`. In other words, whether `ue_ref_rac` is ***in*** that list:

```sql
SELECT
    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"[*]') as combList,
    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList-v1540"[*]') as combListV1540,
    layer3,
   ue_ref_rac, mmes1apid
FROM "S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION" AS s --LIMIT 2000
where ue_ref_rac IN (SELECT reference.MIN1 FROM reference)
```

The error says it all: to use a `=` you need a single thing on both sides of the operator. You can either change it for a proper one-to-many comparison like above or make sure it's always one-to-one.

If `S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION` table has some kind of `tac`, `model` and `vendor` columns you could match with, you can use those to match 1:1 - `reference` is grouped by these three, so this expression should always result in a single value you can safely use `=` with:

```sql
SELECT
    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"[*]') as combList,
    jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList-v1540"[*]') as combListV1540,
    layer3,
   ue_ref_rac, mmes1apid
FROM "S1_UE_CAPABILITY_INFO_INDICATION" AS s --LIMIT 2000
where ue_ref_rac = (SELECT reference.MIN1 FROM reference AS r
                    WHERE r.ue_tac   =s.ue_tac 
                    AND   r.ue_model =s.ue_model
                    AND   r.ue_vendor=s.ue_vendor )
```